# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' - Neural Style Transfer algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I would like to implement a Neural Style Transfer, i.e. transfer the style of one image (style reference) to another image (target_image). Here is the full code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

target_image_path = 'test/Stil/portrait.jpg'
style_ref_image_path = 'test/Stil/style_reference.jpg'

width, height = load_img(target_image_path).size
img_height = 400
img_width = int(width * img_height / height)

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg19

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    img = load_img(image_path, target_size = (img_height, img_width))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    img = vgg19.preprocess_input(img)
    return img
    
def deprocess_image(x):
    x[:, :, 0] += 103.939
    x[:, :, 1] += 116.779
    x[:, :, 2] += 123.68
    x = x[:, :, ::-1]
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')
    return x

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfv1
tfv1.disable_eager_execution() 
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

target_image = K.constant(preprocess_image(target_image_path))
style_ref_image = K.constant(preprocess_image(style_ref_image_path))
combination_image = K.placeholder((1, img_height, img_width, 3))

input_tensor = K.concatenate([target_image, style_ref_image, combination_image], axis=0)
model = vgg19.VGG19(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

def content_loss(base, combination):
    return K.sum(K.square(combination - base))

def gram_matrix(x):
    features = K.batch_flatten(K.permute_dimensions(x, (2, 0, 1)))
    gram = K.dot(features, K.transpose(features))
    return gram
    
def style_loss(style, combination):
    S = gram_matrix(style)
    C = gram_matrix(combination)
    channels = 3
    size = img_height * img_width
    return K.sum(K.square(S - C)) / (4. * (channels ** 2) * (size ** 2))
    
def total_variation_loss(x):
    a = K.square(x[:, :img_height - 1, :img_width - 1, :] - x[:, 1:, :img_width - 1, :])
    b = K.square(x[:,:img_height - 1, :img_width - 1, :] - x[:, :img_height - 1,  1:, :])
    return K.sum(K.pow(a + b, 1.25))
    
outputs_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer.output) for layer in model.layers])
content_layer = 'block5_conv2'
style_layers = ['block1_conv1', 'block2_conv1', 'block3_conv1', 'block4_conv1', 'block5_conv1']

total_variation_weight = 1e-4
style_weight = 1.
content_weight = 0.025

loss = tf.Variable(0.)
layer_features = outputs_dict[content_layer]
target_image_features = layer_features[0, :, :, :]
combination_features = layer_features[2, :, :, :]
loss.assign_add(content_weight * content_loss(target_image_features, combination_features))

for layer_name in style_layers:
    layer_features = outputs_dict[layer_name]
    style_ref_features = layer_features[1, :, :, :]
    combination_features = layer_features[2, :, :, :]
    sl = style_loss(style_ref_features, combination_features)
    loss.assign_add((style_weight / len(style_layers)) * sl)
    
with tf.GradientTape() as gtape:
    loss.assign_add(total_variation_weight * total_variation_loss(combination_image))
    print('loss = ', loss)

grads = gtape.gradient(loss, combination_image)
fetch_loss_and_grads = K.function([combination_image], [loss, grads])

class Evaluator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.loss_value = None
        self.grads_values = None
    def loss(self, x):
        assert self.loss_value is None
        x = x.reshape((1, img_height, img_width, 3))
        outs = fetch_loss_and_grads([x])
        loss_value = outs[0]
        grad_values = outs[1].flatten().astype('float64')
        self.loss_value = loss_value
        self.grad_values = grad_values
        return self.loss_value
    def grads(self, x):
        assert self.loss_value is not None
        grad_values = np.copy(self.grad_values)
        self.loss_value = None
        self.grad_values = None
        return grad_values
        
evaluator = Evaluator()

from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b
import imageio
import time

result_prefix = 'my_result'
iterations = 20
x = preprocess_image(target_image_path)
x = x.flatten() 

for i in range(iterations):
    print('Start iteration: ', i)
    start_time = time.time()
    x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x, fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
    print('Current value of loss function: ', min_val)
    img = x.copy().reshape((img_height, img_width, 3))
    img = deprocess_image(img)
    fname = result_prefix + '_at_iteration_%d.png' % i
    imageio.imwrite(fname, img)
    end_time = time.time()
    print('Iteration %d completed in %ds' % (i, end_time - start_time))
```

I get the following output/error:

```
...
loss =  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
Start iteration:  0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/S.368_Stackoverflow.py", line 122, in <module>
    x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x, fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 198, in fmin_l_bfgs_b
    res = _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args=args, jac=jac, bounds=bounds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 335, in _minimize_lbfgsb
    f, g = func_and_grad(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py", line 285, in func_and_grad
    f = fun(x, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "test/S.368_Stackoverflow.py", line 95, in loss
    outs = fetch_loss_and_grads([x])
  File "/home/mackie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4273, in __call__
    self._make_callable(feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)
  File "/home/mackie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 4202, in _make_callable
    callable_opts.fetch.append(x.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I really tried a lot but I don't see what's the problem. I would be grateful for help.

Tensorflow version: 2.8.0

Python version 3.8.10

Numpy version: 1.22.2

Comment: Can you please provide with missing file, when i ran the code shared i face below error:


FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test/Stil/portrait.jpg'

Comment: @TFer: Thank you for you comment! Unfortunately I don't have the right to provide the pictures. The file "portrait.jpg" is a photo of the German city Tübingen. You can use a Google search to find it but you could also use any other photography. The second one "style_reference.jpg" is a painting, only used for the style. I used "Starry Night" from Vincent van Gogh (again found by a Google search).